# How to create an object with count dynamically in php?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have the data like,

```
data: [{
      0: {
         id: 1
         name: aaa,
      }
      1: {
         id: 2
         name: bbb,
      }
      3: {
         id: 3
         name: ccc,
      }
      4: {
         id: 2
         name: bbb,
      }
      5: {
         id: 1
         name: aaa,
      }
      6: {
         id: 2
         name: bbb,
      }
}]
```

Now i want to get the repeated values count and i want my **end result be like**,

```
data: [{
      0: {
         id: 1
         name: aaa,
         count: 2
      }
      1: {
         id: 2
         name: bbb,
         count: 3
      }
      2: {
         id: 3
         name: ccc,
         count: 1
      }
    }]
```

I tried this code,

```
$loc = []
foreach ($data as $key) {
    if(array_key_exists($key->id,$loc)){
       $loc[$key->id] = $loc[$key->id] + 1;
    }else{
       $loc[$key->id] = 1;
    }
 }
```

It works but the result is something like,

```
{
 1: 2
 2: 3
 3: 1
}
```

But i want to display like i mentioned above. Help me to get the data format right.

Comment: Do you want an object or an array? It's not clear from your symbol usage...

Comment: I edited my code @Nick, i want the result like i mentioned above

Comment: Now you just have an array with the same 1 object embedded in it. What Nick was suggesting is that wouldn't your source data be better formatted as an array with multiple elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you the basic structure you want:

```
$loc = [];
foreach ($data as $key) {
    if(array_key_exists($key->id,$loc)){
       $loc[$key->id]->count++;
    }else{
       $loc[$key->id] = clone $key;
       $loc[$key->id]->count = 1;
    }
}
print_r($loc);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => aaa
            [count] => 2
        )    
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => bbb
            [count] => 3
        )    
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => ccc
            [count] => 1
        )    
)
```

You can then do various manipulations to get something like the JSON you show in your question e.g.

```
echo json_encode((object)['data' => [(object)array_values($loc)]], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "0": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "aaa",
                "count": 2
            },
            "1": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "bbb",
                "count": 3
            },
            "2": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "ccc",
                "count": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BS0cm)

Comment: Thank you @Nick, It is working great. I was looking for this many hours.